# What does "smoosh" mean?

Tags: meaning

I read this sentence in one of my son's picture books:

> "The tire was squashed, the tire was smooshed."

(It's talking about a bike).

The word "smoosh" is strange to me, so I consulted some dictionaries and it surprised me that I couldn't even find an entry for "smoosh".

What does it mean? How come it can't be found in dictionaries but can be found in a kid's book???

Comment: try *smush* instead

Comment: So it's an informal pronounciation of "smush", which means "crush" or "smash"? I guess it's a deliberately mistaken word to suggest it is used by kids?

Comment: @dennylv: I don' think so. A simple google search gave the result. But not in some dictionaries i searched.

Comment: Yeah, why didn't I google? I even consulted the Webster's Collegiate Dictionary and Oxford American Dictionary...So I just didn't think of googling...:)

Comment: Maybe my poor English expression would let me be got wrong. I mean no offense or anything irritating. I am just wondering why it's not available in paper dictionaries.

Comment: dennylv, it is strange. It is not used in the UK. Neither is *smush*, which was mentioned by Jim.

Comment: It's not an informal pronunciation — it's a variant spelling; *smush* rhymes with *bush*, not *brush*, and *smoosh* is supposed to be pronounced with the vowel in *book*, which is the same vowel as in *bush*.

Comment: It's kindergarten slang which seems to have made its way into mainstream American.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/smoosh):

> **Smoosh (v):** squash, crush, or flatten.
>
> *‘use a sharp knife so as not to smoosh the broccoli’*

Comment: Thank you. I am still curious why it's not available in mainstream dictionaries?

Comment: Maybe because it is very informal. Anyways, you could find it here: [Smoosh in the American Heritage Dictionary](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/smoosh)

Comment: Wiktionary defines it as the alternative spelling of Smush.

Comment: It is indeed a rather hard word to locate in online dictionaries. For situations like this, I recommend [OneLook.com](http://www.onelook.com), which is a website that searches for words in a host of online dictionaries. In the case of [_smoosh_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=smoosh&ls=a), that word is found in only 7 or 8 dictionaries (as opposed to say, [_smash_](http://www.onelook.com/?w=smash&ls=a), which is found in almost 30, plus over a dozen other specialized dictionaries as well).

Comment: Thank you. That website is really supportive and effective. It does fit for my use.

Comment: This entire answer is copied from http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/smoosh

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a bit informal word but you may find in almost all reputed dictionaries like oxford dictionaries or merriam webster

Its general meaning is to *flatten or smash*